# Need to split the file based on empty line using Batch script

Tags: batch-file

I need to split one file when ever the empty records starts,File contains multiple file structure in the same file need to split the files using batch script.

Important, that every sub file is separated by empty record

so the data look like: test.csv

```
sno,employee name,address,location,zip code
1,aaaa,12/34,Hyderabad,500089
2,bbbb,12/35/44,chennai,500079
3,cccc,12/31/11,pune,500069

Cardnumber,cardname,card type,card limit
12345,visa,diamond,10000
2345,master,platinum,50000

Accno,bank name,branch code,Branch location
98765,sbi,23456,hyd
12457,citi,8765,usa
4444,axis,78767,India
```

and I need separate file like below
Test1.csv

```
sno,employye name,address,location,zipcode
1,aaaa,12/34,Hyderabad,500089
2,bbbb,12/35/44,chennai,500079
3,cccc,12/31/11,pune,500069
```

Test2.csv

```
Cardnumber,cardname,card type,card limit
12345,visa,diamond,10000
2345,master,platinum,50000
```

Test3.csv

```
Accno,bank name,branch code,Branch location
98765,sbi,23456,hyd
12457,citi,8765,usa
4444,axis,78767,india
```

I have tried below script but it is not working as expected.

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set c=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (test.csv) do (
if "%%a" equ "\n" (
set /a c+=1
>f!c!.csv echo.
) else (
>> f!c!.csv echo %%a
)
)
```

Please help me to write the batch script for the above requirement. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are the Header lines the only ones, that start with a letter (like in your example)?

Comment: I doubt that @Stephan, the examples combine data from multiple banks and countries. I do not like the idea that somebody who doesn't know what they are doing has access to information as sensitive as this. _I can't wait until the new General Data Protection Regulations come into force here_.

Comment: @Stephen: NO, Detail records also start with letters, just i created sample  file with test data because not able to share the original file format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for /f` ignores empty lines. So you need a little trick for lines *not*  to be empty. `find /n` adds a line number to each line, so it isn't empty any more.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set c=0
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%a in ('type t.txt^|find /n /v ""') do (
  REM echo A %%a    B %%b
  if "%%b" equ "" (
    set /a c+=1
    >f!c!.csv echo.
  ) else (
    >> f!c!.csv echo %%b
  )
)
```

The `REM` line is left from troubleshooting, but I left it there because it may help you understand, what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for your help ,i am able to split the file which you provided. we have one more requirement ..