# Break down a file which has 3 structures in it separated by an empty line and append the data from 3 structures in 3 separate newly create files

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to break down a file which has 3 structures in it separated by an empty line and append the data from 3 structures in 3 separate newly created files, each for each structure

I have 100s of file Each with 3 structures separated by an empty line ( listed below ), for all the 100s of files the structure remains same.

for sample i am taking 2 files ( which has 3 structures )

files:
2018-02-02_hyderabad_hour_12.csv,
 2018-02-02_hyderabad_hour_13.csv

**Sturctures for File "2018-02-02_hyderabad_hour_12.csv":**

```
 sno,employee name,address,location,zip code
    1,aaaa,12/34,Hyderabad,500089
    2,bbbb,12/35/44,chennai,500079
    3,cccc,12/31/11,pune,500069

    Cardnumber,cardname,card type,card limit
    12345,visa,diamond,10000
    2345,master,platinum,50000

    Accno,bank name,branch code,Branch location,IFSE code
    98765,sbi,23456,hyd,IFSE001
    12457,citi,8765,usa,IFSE002
    4444,axis,78767,India,IFSE003
```

**Sturctures for File "2018-02-02_hyderabad_hour_13.csv":**

```
sno,employee name,address,location,zip code
4,QQQQ,12/34,DELHI,500089
5,RRRR,12/35/44,NOIDA,500079
6,SSSS,12/31/11,KOLKATA,500069

Cardnumber,cardname,card type,card limit
67890,visa,diamond,10000
8976,amex,platinum,50000

Accno,bank name,branch code,Branch location, IFSE code
98765,hdfc,23456888,hyd,IFSE004
12457,kotak,876588,usa,IFSE005
4444,bod,78767888,India,IFSE006
```

we are able to break each file in to three different files based on their structures i.e.the file "2018-02-02_hyderabad_hour_12.csv" is now broken in to 3 files

```
FIle1_2018-02-02_hyderabad_hour_12.csv
File2_2018-02-02_hyderabad_hour_12.csv
File3_2018-02-02_hyderabad_hour_12.csv
```

but i am not able to append the data from second file "2018-02-02_hyderabad_hour_13.csv" in to the same files created ( above )

Now, i would like to have only 3 files each for each structure e.g (  for the 2 files which i took in the sample, i am expecting only 3 files which holds the data for structure 1, structure 2 and structure 3 respectively )
i.e. i want a batch script which will append the data in one single file from multiple files, as below

`File1_2018-02-02_hyderabad_hour.csv` should have datas only from structure 1 from  `2018-02-02_hyderabad_hour_12.csv` and `2018-02-02_hyderabad_hour_13.csv`
`File2_2018-02-02_hyderabad_hour.csv` should have datas only from structure 2 from  `2018-02-02_hyderabad_hour_12.csv` and `2018-02-02_hyderabad_hour_13.csv`
`File3_2018-02-02_hyderabad_hour.csv` should have datas only from structure 3 from  `2018-02-02_hyderabad_hour_12.csv` and `2018-02-02_hyderabad_hour_13.csv`

**Expected output file:**
**File1_2018-02-02_hyderabad_hour.csv**

```
sno,employee name,address,location,zip code,city
1,aaaa,12/34,Hyderabad,500089,hyderabad
2,bbbb,12/35/44,chennai,500079,hyderabad
3,cccc,12/31/11,pune,500069,hyderabad
4,QQQQ,12/34,DELHI,500089,hyderabad
5,RRRR,12/35/44,NOIDA,500079,hyderabad
6,SSSS,12/31/11,KOLKATA,500069,,hyderabad
```

**File2_2018-02-02_hyderabad_hour.csv**

```
Cardnumber,cardname,card type,card limit,city
12345,visa,diamond,10000,hyderabad
2345,master,platinum,50000,hyderabad
67890,visa,diamond,10000,hyderabad
8976,amex,platinum,50000,hyderabad
```

**File3_2018-02-02_hyderabad_hour.csv**

```
Accno,bank name,branch code,Branch location, IFSE code,city
98765,sbi,23456,hyd,IFSE001,hyderabad
12457,citi,8765,usa,IFSE002,hyderabad
4444,axis,78767,India,IFSE003,hyderabad
98765,hdfc,23456888,hyd,IFSE004,hyderabad
12457,kotak,876588,usa,IFSE005,hyderabad
4444,bod,78767888,India,IFSE006,hyderabad
```

I have updated required output files with the expected structure.

Please help me for the solution . Thanks in Advance.

Comment: are the strings like `<CardInfo_Structure2>` part of the file(s) or did you insert them for explanation?

Comment: How different to the [question you asked two days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48538589/6738015) and @Stephan answered is this question?

Comment: <CardInfo_Structure2> Is part of the Explanation and it is not there in the file

Comment: Are the header lines for each section in your real environment exactly as in your examples above,  or have you included those only for effect too?

Comment: The headers which I provided is just an example for structure of the file . In the actual file header columns are more because of security reasons not able to share the actual file. Thanks

Comment: I absolutely do not believe that the field names in those headers can be considered confidential information. There is an obvious reason to protect the fields below them by providing fake details which follow the correct string data format and possibly some parts of the filenames as long as their structure/naming convention is accurate. As you can see by the answer very kindly provided @Stephan, those headers are dependent. It will be almost impossible for us to script reasonable answers when all of the information you have provided in your question is irrelevant to your real world situation.

Comment: I wonder, how/why data from three obviously independent sources got into the same file. Something seems wrong with the whole process.

Comment: I also wonder why the code you've used is that which @Stephan provided in your previous question. Using it implies that it solved your issue, yet you haven't shown your gratitude by marking their answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "n=0"
for %%f in (*.csv) do (
   set "input=%%f"
   set "header="
   for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" "%%f"') do (
      if not defined header (
         set "header=%%b"
         set /A "n=n%%3+1"
         set "output=File!n!_!input:~0,-7!.txt"
         if not exist "!output!" > "!output!" echo !header!
      ) else if "%%b" neq "" (
         >> "!output!" echo %%b
      ) else (
         set "header="
      )
   )
)
ren *.txt *.csv
```

Comment: Thank you for response. I have ran your code and it is generating 4 output files instead of 3 output files , for this <BAnkInfo_Structure3> structure it is generating 2 files and while appending the 2nd source file data to output file it is excluding first line the 2nd source file. Please help me to generate 3 output files with respective data. Thanks in Advance

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand your explanation and you have not provided the most basic info, like the names of the 4 output files. I tested the program with the data you posted here and edited my answer with the generated output. I suggest you to do _exaclty the same_ and then review your input files...

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and for generated output. It is my bad for explanation purpose  In source files (2018-02-02_hyderabad_hour_12.csv,2018-02-02_hyderabad_hour_13.csv)            i have given                                                               <EmpInfo_Structure1>,
<CardInfo_Structure2>
<BAnkInfo_Structure3>  but actually these records won't come in the source file. Kindly remove those lines from source file . Please please execute one more time. It is giving 4 output files.

Comment: Aacini , not able to add my output here because of length of the output that reason I am asking you to kindly execute once . Please remove the <EmpInfo_Structure1>, <CardInfo_Structure2> <BAnkInfo_Structure3>  records from  source file and please execute the batch script

Comment: Mmmm, this becomes worst... Please, read carefully: **1.** Formatting facilities in this site are used to help readers to understand your problem. You clearly included the `<EmpInfo_Structure1>` and the other structure lines **INSIDE** the files! **2.** If your problem is about "split several files in three parts", then you should realize that the over-mentioned "EmpInfo_Structure1" and the other names are completely irrelevant for the process! IMHO you would be happy if the program generates 3 output files with any names, like `File1_2018-02-02_hyderabad_hour.csv`, etc; isn't it?

Comment: I suggest you to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48588061/edit) and eliminate all erroneous and irrelevant data (or close it and post a new one)...

Comment: i I have edited my question with the source file data and requied output file format ,as per your comment need 3 output file with any names, like File1_2018-02-02_hyderabad_hour.csv, File2_2018-02-02_hyderabad_hour.csv, File3_2018-02-02_hyderabad_hour.csv .   Thanks in Advance

Comment: Code for _new_ requirements added... **:(**

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, It is working as expected:):)

Comment: Your solution is working as expected, we have one more requirement and need to achive through this solution .

Requirement:
1) Need to Add the one more column(City) in the output files and need to copy the location name from file name(2018-02-02_hyderabad_hour_13.csv) and the column value should be "hyderbad" from file name. I have update required output files in the question. Please please help us to achieve this solution .

Comment: please help me to achieve the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Your "one more requirement" leads to a complete different approach:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%x in (2018-??-??_hyderabad_hour_??.csv) do (
  for /f "tokens=1-6 delims=-_" %%a in ("%%~nx") do (
    for /f "delims=" %%A in (%%x) do (
      if "%%A"=="sno,employee name,address,location,zip code" set "file=EmpInfo_Structure1_%%a-%%b-%%c_%%d_%%e.csv"
      if "%%A"=="Cardnumber,cardname,card type,card limit" set "file=CardInfo_Structure2_%%a-%%b-%%c_%%d_%%e.csv"
      if "%%A"=="Accno,bank name,branch code,Branch location,IFSE code" set "file=BankInfo_Structure3_%%a-%%b-%%c_%%d_%%e.csv"
      if not exist "!file!" >"!file!" echo %%A
      >>!file! (echo %%A|findstr /vbc:"sno,employee name," /vbc:"Cardnumber,cardname," /vbc:"Accno,bank name," ) 
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much stephan for quick response. It is working fine but when ever the detail records data having '&' and   then it is not populating the data for those rows which having the characters '&'.

Comment: Extending to first comment.    In header if column name having the '%'  it is not at all generating the files and populating the data , if I remove the '%' from column name it is working fine  EX: Card limit %   .   Please help me to achieve these.   Thanks in Advance